# Foreign key Entity relationship using Springboot/JPA

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I have 2 entities a customer and order. A customer can have many orders and it has been defined as follows

```
@Entity
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
public class Order {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long orderID;
private long discountValue;
private long totalValue;

@ManyToOne
private Customer customer;

private Order(){

}

public Order(long discountValue, long totalValue) {
    this.discountValue = discountValue;
    this.totalValue = totalValue;
}

public void setDiscountValue(long discountValue) {
    this.discountValue = discountValue;
}


public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
    this.customer = customer;
}
}
```

The customer entity being :

```
@Entity
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
public class Customer {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long customerID;
private String name;
private CustomerType type;
private long totalDiscount;
private int numberOfOrders;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
private List<Order> orders;

private Customer(){

}

public Customer(String name, CustomerType type, long totalOrderPlaced, long totalDiscount) {
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
    this.totalDiscount = totalDiscount;
}

public Customer(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setType(CustomerType type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public void setTotalDiscount(long totalDiscount) {
    this.totalDiscount = totalDiscount;
}

public void setNumberOfOrders(int numberOfOrders) {
    this.numberOfOrders = numberOfOrders;
}
}
```

When I run the above as a spring boot application I can see the following exceptions and I am not sure how I can solve this;

```
     Hibernate: create table customer (customerid int8 not null, name varchar(255), number_of_orders int4 not null, total_discount int8 not null, type int4, primary key (customerid))
     Hibernate: create table order (orderid int8 not null, discount_value int8 not null, total_value int8 not null, customer_customerid int8, primary key (orderid))
     2019-02-06 16:06:52.416  WARN 23822 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table order (orderid int8 not null, discount_value int8 not null, total_value int8 not null, customer_customerid int8, primary key (orderid))" via JDBC Statement

     org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table order (orderid int8 not null, discount_value int8 not null, total_value int8 not null, customer_customerid int8, primary key (orderid))" via JDBC Statement
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:277) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:71) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:310) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:939) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) [spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) [spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) [spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1083) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:853) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at com.example.OrderMgmt.Application.main(Application.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
   Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "order"
   Position: 14
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:307) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:293) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:270) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:266) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
... 34 common frames omitted

 Hibernate: create sequence hibernate_sequence start 1 increment 1
 Hibernate: alter table if exists order add constraint FK8ccclx3o3ri8niyrd8vv85xdy foreign key (customer_customerid) references customer
2019-02-06 16:06:52.507  WARN 23822 --- [           main] 

o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table if exists order add constraint FK8ccclx3o3ri8niyrd8vv85xdy foreign key (customer_customerid) references customer" via JDBC Statement

   org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table if exists order add constraint FK8ccclx3o3ri8niyrd8vv85xdy foreign key (customer_customerid) references customer" via JDBC Statement
    at 
  org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applyForeignKeys(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:433) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
```

I have tried modifying the application.properties with multiple options.

Application.properties looks like this :

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=30
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

Comment: Add a `@JoinColumn` to specify your foreign key.

Comment: @akuma8 tried adding the JoinColumn annotation; to the Order Entity and I still see the error. Updating my application.properties in the question

Comment: Try again by changing the table name `ORDER` to `CUSTOMER_ORDER`

Comment: How did you configure the `@JoinColumn` annotation, could you edit your post to show it?

Comment: @akuma8 thanks for pointing that out; I had not put in annotation in the right manner. I will update the answer to this question

Answer (score 0):

Changed entity order to customerOrder and made the following changes in the CustomerOrder Class with the @JoinColumn annotation.

```
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customerID", nullable = false)
    private Customer customer;
```